# I have latest versions of php, laravel installed.I want to use the projects which are built on different versions .How can I do that not uninstalling?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have latest versions of php ann laravel installed.Now I want to use the projects which are built on different frameworks.How can I do that without uninstalling xampp?

I tried using commands

```
composer update
```

It throwed me some errors

my current versions :  "php": "^8.1", "laravel/framework": "^10.0",

project to work on :   "php": "^7.3|^8.0","laravel/framework": "^8.65",

After running this command on cmd

PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelproject> composer update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.28, ..., 3.1.30] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.16.* -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0].
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.31, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.28.0].
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.27 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.16 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0, ..., 1.28.0].
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.28.0].
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.28.0] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
- Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to speciPS C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelproject> composer update --with-all-dependencies (-W)
-W : The term '-W' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:42

- composer update --with-all-dependencies (-W)
- ```
                                       ~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-W:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelproject> composer update --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.28, ..., 3.1.30] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.16.* -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0].
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.31, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.28.0].
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.27 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.16 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0, ..., 1.28.0].
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.28.0].
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.28.0] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
- Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Comment: *ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension*

Comment: You have to dockerize the projects, so each project has its own php version and whatever they need... Use Laravel Sail or learn how to use Docker Compose so you can create your own. Uninstall XAMPP as in the professional place, using XAMPP is an insult, is like using your fingers to count when trying to do a complex operation as a physicist... Upgrade your knowledge to the next level, docker 100%